# Nothing change when using search and sort function in flexigrid codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, flexigrid

I can display data grid well when using flexigrid library in codeigniter, but when I use function sorting and searching it can't run as I hope before. Nothing change and just load the first page. The problem is in searching and sorting, paging function is ok.

Maybe it 's something wrong with my code, and need help. Thanks.

```
//Controller
public function daftarKomoditi()
{
    $colModel['dig10'] = array('Kode Komoditi KBKI',120,TRUE,'left',2);
    $colModel['desk10'] = array('Jenis Komoditi',453,TRUE,'left',2);

    $gridParams = array(
        'width' => '600',
        'height' => 'auto',
        'rp' => 10,
        'singleSelect' => true,
        'rpOptions' => '[10,15,20,25,40]',
        'pagestat' => 'Displaying: {from} to {to} of {total} items.',
        'blockOpacity' => 0.5,
        'title' => 'Master Komoditi SHPB 2013',
        'showTableToggleBtn' => false
    );

    $buttons[] = array('Refresh','refresh','test');
    $buttons[] = array('separator');

    $grid_js = build_grid_js('flex2',site_url("/ajax/getKomoditiList"),$colModel,'id','asc',$gridParams,$buttons);

    $data['js_grid'] = $grid_js;  

    $this->load->view('kualitas/komoditi_list',$data);
}

public function getKomoditiList()
{  
    $valid_fields = array('dig10,desk10');
    $this->flexigrid->validate_post('dig10','asc',$valid_fields);

    $records = $this->KualitasModel->getDaftarKomoditi();
    $this->output->set_header($this->config->item('json_header'));

    foreach ($records['records']->result() as $row) {   
        $record_items[] = array($row->dig10,
        $row->dig10,  
        ucfirst(strtolower($row->desk10)),
        );
    }

    $this->output->set_output($this->flexigrid->json_build($records['record_count'],$record_items));        
}

//Model
    function getDaftarKomoditi() //Flexigrid
{
    $table_name = "shpb_mkbki_dig10";

    $this->db->select('*')->from($table_name);
    $this->CI->flexigrid->build_query();

    //Get contents
    $return['records'] = $this->db->get();

    //Build count query
    $this->db->select('count(dig10) as record_count')->from($table_name);
    $this->CI->flexigrid->build_query(FALSE);
    $record_count = $this->db->get();
    $row = $record_count->row();

    //Get Record Count
    $return['record_count'] = $row->record_count;

    //Return all
    return $return;                                        

}
```

Comment: browser console errors?

Comment: @tomexsans :Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'outerWidth'

Answer (score 0):

Here is my Flexigrid implementation in CodeIgniter 2.2, view demo examples and download: http://ci-flexigrid.sameershemna.com/